# Lenovo u310 will not charge when turned on

Tags: 12.10, laptop, power-management, lenovo, ultrabook

I've looked around and had several friends have a look but we cannot figure this out.

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a Lenovo U310. The laptop charges fine when the laptop is off but it will not charge when Ubuntu is running. When I plug it in, ACPI recognizes that the charger is plugged in and charges for a second or two before going back to a state of discharging.

**EDIT:**
The battery is definitely draining over time even if it is plugged in.

Here is the output for when ACPI acknowledges that the charger is plugged in for a few seconds.

```
acpi -b -a
Battery 0: Charging, 52%, charging at zero rate - will never fully charge.
Adapter 0: on-line
```

**EDIT 2:**
This could well be a hardware problem. I've made a fresh install of Windows 7 with correct drivers and I'm getting the same issue. I can run off of the A/C by disconnecting the battery so I know the adapter is fine.

Comment: Have you tested, to see if it is not charging, or just reporting that it is not charging?

Comment: If I leave the laptop on, it will die. The battery percentage has dropped 30% since this morning and its been plugged in all day.

Comment: +1, Hope someone can help, I am just helping with making sure the question is clear. A second question that may help. Does it charge if when you boot you go into BIOS for an hour, or stay in the grub boot loader.

Comment: I will try this later.

Comment: Simular to [this case](https://superuser.com/questions/631574/battery-sort-of-died-after-a-power-outage/631583#631583), very probably a hardware failure within the battery itself, common on old ones.